# Angular - How to have HTML listening on observable

Tags: angular, observable

In the app I'm working on, there is a top bar menu where the user information is displayed, if the user is logged in, picture and name is displayed. If is not logged in, the button "log in" appears.

However, in order to check the changes, the page needs to be refreshed. I have come to an idea that is use an observable so it changes dynamically as it should be listening the whole time.

**app.component.ts**

```
isLoggedIn;
 subscription= this.authService.dataofIsLoggedIn.subscribe(data =>{
    this.isLoggedIn = data;
 });        

 ngOnInit(){
        this.authService.currentUser.subscribe(data => {
          var User = data;
          this.menuItem = [];
            if(User){
             console.log("do user stuff");
          }
        });
      }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<span class="VCenterFlex">
  <button
    (click)="router.navigate(['/auth/login'])"
    *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"
    mat-raised-button
    color="accent"
  >
    Login <mat-icon>meeting_room</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="avatarimageContainer_parent">
  <div
    class="avatarimageContainer"
    *ngIf="isLoggedIn"
    (click)="router.navigate(['/profile'])"
  >
    <img class="avatarimage" src="{{ user.avatar }}" />
    <img class="settings_avatar_top" src="../assets/img/settings_icon.png">
  </div>

  </div>

  <h6 style="margin-right: 5px;" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    Hi, {{ user.name }}.
  </h6>
  <button
    *ngIf="isLoggedIn"
    (click)="authService.logout()"
    type="button"
    mat-raised-button
    color="accent"
  >
    <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon> Logout
  </button>
</span>
```

As it is, When I log in (not refreshing) the information is not displayed until the user changes the route. I wonder if a listening action can be performed so if there is log in information, it automatically changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncPipe` in your template.
With `AsyncPipe`we can use promises and observables directly in our template, without having to store the result on an intermediate property or variable.
You will be using something like this:

`{{ obj_expression | async }}`

where obj_expression could be your observable, promise or subject.

Comment: I will check on AsyncPipe to see how it works. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This should be used creating a template in the ts file, right?

Comment: Correct, you will be using your observable with `async` pipe.

Comment: Ok, for clear understanding l am editing my answer;

Comment: in case I want to access data inside, lets say user.name or user.address, how should I write it? {{user.name | async }} seems not to be working.

Comment: Nope, you can use async pipe with observables only. In your case user is var type object.

Comment: Decalre user on the top of your component. and in your html, use something like: `{{user?.name}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219198/discussion-between-german-and-neeraj-shende).